# R resample data to a log-normal distribution

Tags: r, resampling

I have a set of simulated data that are roughly uniformly distributed.  I would like to sample a subset of these data and for that subset to have a log-normal distribution with a (log)mean and (log)standard deviation that I specify.

I can figure out some slow brute-force ways to do this, but I feel like there should be a way to do it in a couple lines using the `plnorm` function and the `sample` function with the "prob" variable set.  I can't seem to get the behavior I'm looking for though.  My first attempt was something like:

```
probs <- plnorm(orig_data, meanlog = mu, sdlog = sigma)
new_data <- sample(orig_data, replace = FALSE, prob = probs)
```

I think I'm misinterpreting the way the `plnorm` function behaves.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `qlnorm` not `plnorm`. When mapping from the uniform to another distribution, you should just use the inverse cdf or quantile function. All of the R distribution functions use the same prefixes (q,p, etc.) to identify which is which.

Answer (score 1):

If your `orig_data` are uniformly distributed between 0 and 1, then

```
new_data = qlnorm(orig_data, meanlog = mu, sdlog = sigma)
```

will give log sampled data. IF your data aren't between 0 and 1 but say `a` and `b` then first:

```
orig_data = (orig_data-a)/(b-a)
```

Generally speaking, uniform RV between 0 and 1 are seen as probability so if you want to sample from a given distribution with it, you have to use `q...` ie take the corresponding quantile

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the suggestions.  While they get me close, I've decided on a slightly different approach for my particular problem, which I'm posting as the solution in case it's useful to others.

One specific I left out of the original question is that I have a whole data set (stored as a data frame), and I want to resample rows from that set such that one of the variables (columns) is log-normally distributed.  Here is the function I wrote to accomplish this, which relies on `dlnorm` to calculate probabilities and `sample` to resample the data frame:

```
resample_lognorm <- function(origdataframe,origvals,meanlog,sdlog,n) {
  prob <- dlnorm(origvals,meanlog=log(10)*meanlog,sdlog=log(10)*sdlog)
  newsamp <- origdataframe[sample(nrow(origdataframe),
                                  size=n,replace=FALSE,prob=prob),]
  return(newsamp)
}
```

In this case `origdataframe` is the full data frame I want to sample from, and `originals` is the column of data I want to resample to a log-normal distribution.  Note that the log(10) factors in `meanlog` and `sdlog` are because I want the distribution to be log-normal in base 10, not natural log.